# jq combine output on a single line separated by space

Tags: jq

I am trying to run a `jq` query on a windows machine and it extracts values from output on a separate line

```
jq -r .Accounts[].Id
```

Output

```
204359864429
224271824096
282276286062
210394168456
090161402717
```

How do I run the `jq` query so that it combines the output on a single line separated by space

This is what I need-

```
204359864429 224271824096 282276286062 210394168456 090161402717
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 27):

The usual way would be to use the `@csv` or `@tsv` operators to convert the result in the CSV or tab-delimited format. These operators need the result to be contained in an array. For your case also to have a single space delimit, we can do a simple `join(" ")` operation

```
jq -r '[.Accounts[].Id]|join(" ")'
```

Comment: That did not work. I am running this                                                           
   <command> | jq -r '[.Accounts[].Id]|join(" ")'
This is the error I am getting.
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
[.Accounts[].Id]|join(
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: On Windows, you would either use double-quotation marks to quote the filter, or use the -f option to avoid all the issues that typically entails.  Also, in the spirit of the [mcve] guidelines, it is usually a good idea to include a minimal example of the input that you are giving jq.  @Inian's answer basically assumes it is a single JSON object.

Comment: Wrapping the output in () worked for me. Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177843/parse-one-field-from-an-json-array-into-bash-array

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `@sh` formatter:

`jq -r ".Accounts[].Id | @sh"`

From the jq docs:

> The input is escaped suitable for use in a command-line for a POSIX shell. If the input is an array, the output will be a series of space-separated strings.

Reference:

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters

Answer (score 3):

At first I thought the `join()` solution above did not work.  Then I realized that I was "overfeeding" the `join()` filter, causing it to fail because I was providing more than a simple array as input.  I had concatenated several filters with `,` and failed to limit the scope of my `join()`.

### Did not work:

```
jq -r \
'.ansible_facts |
 .ansible_hostname,
 .ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | join(" "),
 .ansible_local."aws-public-ipv4".publicIP'
```

This gave the error,

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over string ("hostone")
```

because jq was attempting to "consume" not only `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` but also the output of the preceding `ansible_hostname` filter (I am not certain why this is or whether it was even intended by the author of jq).

### Does work:

```
jq -r \
'.ansible_facts |
 .ansible_hostname,
 (.ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | join(" ")),
 .ansible_local."aws-public-ipv4".publicIP'
```

Here, I restrict `join()` to `.ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` only (`ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` is an array of IP addresses I wish to translate into a single, space-separated string).

---

**P.S.:** I found that the `@sh` filter produces space-separated output as desired, but in addition *delimits each output item in single quotes*.

---

**P.P.S.:**
Here was my workaround, until I discovered that `join()` works just the same as it when used properly (see above):

```
jq -r '.Accounts[].Id | @tsv | sub("\t";" ";"g")'
```

**Explanation**: the `@tsv` filter produces **T**ab **S**eparated **V**alues, then the `sub()` filter substitutes tabs with spaces, **g**lobally.

Answer (score 3):

If you run jq in a shell, you can use `xargs` like below:

```
jq -r .Accounts[].Id | xargs
```

output:

```
204359864429 224271824096 282276286062 210394168456 090161402717
```

The best parts of this way is if you have more fields you can add more control:

```
jq -r '.Accounts[] | .Id, .Name' | xargs -n2
```

The output like below:

```
204359864429 A
224271824096 B
282276286062 C
210394168456 D
090161402717 E
```